# What's the significance of # in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following code to create an object type in Oracle (PL??)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STAFF_T as OBJECT(Staff_ID# NUMBER, Person PERSON_T); \
```

I'd like to know what is the significance of the # appended to the Staff_ID variable in the declaration?

Comment: Some people use # as an abbreviation for "number". E.g. `POLICY#` would be pronounced "Policy Number". In your case it'd be "Staff ID Number" I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever wrote the code probably didn't mean anything special by #.

But # apparently means something to Oracle, although I don't know what.  From the [SQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements008.htm):

> Oracle strongly discourages you from
>   using $ and # in nonquoted
>   identifiers.

Here are some guesses for what the warning is about:

- it's related to a really old bug (the
  warning goes back to at least Oracle
  7)
- Oracle plans to do something with
  it in a future verison
- that character
  isn't available on all keyboards, character sets, or platforms that Oracle supports

The data dictionary uses the number sign a lot, and as far as I can tell it works just fine for user objects.  But just to be safe you might want to remove it.

Comment: I doubt it's an old bug, because lots of Oracle's data dictionary uses them.  For instance the SERIAL# column in V$SESSION.

Comment: I believe this is for compatibility reasons. `#`, for instance, is a comment in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 11):

No special meaning.

Oracle allows using `$`, `_` and `#` in identifiers, just like any other alphanumeric characters, but the identifier should begin with an alpha character (a letter).

Answer (score 4):

That's part of the column name `Staff_ID#`. The pound sign is an allowable part of an identifier (table/column name) in PL/SQL. See [here](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Oracle+PL+SQL+Language+Pocket+Reference/Chapter+1.+Oracle+PLSQL+Language+Pocket+Reference/1.4+PLSQL+Language+Fundamentals/)